# CSS text element destroys div positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm working on webpage and divided it into several divs before adding text in it.

but when i put some text in one of that divs, all divs position just collapses.

I've made simple code to show the problem.

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper{
  height: 100%;
}

.box{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}

#box-1{
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;

  height: 35%;
  width: 35%;
}

#box-2{
  top: 5%;
  left: 10%;

  height: 35%;
  width: 50%;
}

#box-3{
  top: 10%;
  left: 5%;

  height: 50%;
  width: 35%;
  }

#box-4{
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;

  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Issue</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="box-1" class="box">
   
  </div>
  <div id="box-2" class="box">
   
  </div>
  <div id="box-3" class="box">
   
  </div>
  <div id="box-4" class="box">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it is divided well without problem(at least in my opinion)

But as soon as you add the text in the div, it just collapse and I can't see why.

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper{
  height: 100%;
}

.box{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
}

#box-1{
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;

  height: 35%;
  width: 35%;
}

#box-2{
  top: 5%;
  left: 10%;

  height: 35%;
  width: 50%;
}

#box-3{
  top: 10%;
  left: 5%;

  height: 50%;
  width: 35%;
}

#box-4{
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;

  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

p{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="box-1" class="box">
   <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box-2" class="box">
   
  </div>
  <div id="box-3" class="box">
   
  </div>
  <div id="box-4" class="box">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It collapses whether p tag exists or not.

Divs are positioned with %unit and it is relative.

So it should be relevent only to it's parent and brothers in my thought.

Should I reallocate all of them with absolute position?

If you know why, or have solution, please teach me.
thank you!

Comment: why you give every div `position and top left` it's work without position .

Comment: @lalitbhakuni I wanted divs to be where I want, not just being listed in order. For that, I should give all divs position:inline-block so they can be in same row.

Comment: why you set the `position like top:50% left:50%`

Comment: @lalitbhakuni Do you mean I should set position `top:50%; left:50%;`?. Or are you asking why did I do that? Well in that case, I didn't. What I did is something like `height:50%; width:50%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `vertical-align: top;` to `.box` by default it has `vertical-align: baseline;`

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works! So the problem was that I know nothing about property `vertical-align` :) thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative beside Ismail Farooq's answer

```
.box {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `flexbox` link is [Flexbox here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```html
<html>
<style>
html{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper{
  height: 100vh;
   display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box{
    display: flex;
    background: black;
    margin: 0.5%;
}

#box-1{
    height: 50%;
    width: 49%;
}

#box-2{
    height: 50%;
    width: 49%;
}

#box-3{
    height: 50%;
    width: 49%;
}

#box-4{
    height: 50%;
    width: 49%;
}

p{
  color: white;
}
</style>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="box-1" class="box">
   <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box-2" class="box">
   
  </div>
  <div id="box-3" class="box">
   
  </div>
  <div id="box-4" class="box">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```